AWS Redshift Specturum, AWS GLUE, AWS S3 private vpc
I have a next challenge.
I have a S3 bucket attached with the policy which deny all requests to the bucket if it not comes from VPC Endpoint. Basically I made it to work only within VPC.
I have a AWS Glue service which used as a Data Catalog.
I have a Redshift provisioned cluster with the "enhanced VPC routing" enabled to make redshift works only in internal vpc.
I checked the documentation
"Redshift Spectrum doesn't support enhanced VPC routing with provisioned clusters."
When I used "UNLOAD" query directly from redshift to S3 it worked.
I also deployed vpc endpoint for the AWS GLUE service.
When I do select over the AWS GLUE I receive the error:
  error:  S3CurlException: Connection timed out after 50001 milliseconds, CurlError 28, multiCurlError 0, CanRetry 1, UserError 0
  code:      15007
  context:   Unable to fetch S3 metadata for prefix=folder/folder2/sp_file
  query:     3846641
  location:  scan_range_manager.cpp:496
  process:   padbmaster [pid=1073799548]

I cant understand where is the issue.
If the issue is Redshift Specturum with "enhanced routing enabled" then why UNLOAD query works directly to the Redshift ?
Maybe anybody has experience with such solution ?
To use Redshift Specturum, AWS GLUE and Private S3 together ?

If you go to job details tab → Connections section, you can set the VPC in there.

@Bogdan I am not using any job at AWS GLUE.
I am using it as a Data Catalog

Handy link to achive this solution.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/enhance-data-security-and-governance-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum-with-vpc-endpoints/
In my case, my redshift cluster was deployed in a wrong subnet. Because subnet groupt picks random subnet.
The link explains fully private without internet access, but you can also keep nat gateway if you want internet access.
